# sendmailR adding extra space in HTML body that ocasionally breaks HTML tags

Tags: html, css, r, doctype, sendmailr

I automated personalized reports for people on my team and it's working great!

The only problem is that some of the emails occasionally have an extra space in the middle of the HTML body. Occasionally, these extra spaces are positioned such that they break and expose an HTML tag:

*For example, **"Consul invidunt"** would read **"Consul invi dunt"**. Or worse it would read **"< p> Consul invidunt"** with the paragraph tag exposed due to the extra space.*

The only thing that kind of works is creating "space traps". For example, adding `<p>                           </p>` right after the paragraph and hoping that the extra paragraph "lands" in the middle of the paragraph that is just a bunch of spaces. It doesn't always work though.

Since the data frames in the middle of the body and the recipient names are variable, this issue only occurs with some recipients. Those recipients with the glitch change depending on what I type in the body, whether I try to "catch" the space with a "space trap", etc.

The weird thing is that if I paste the HTML from `bodyhtml[['text']]` into an HTML editor, the HTML looks perfect!

I've also checked to see whether this is a problem with Outlook, but the problem persists when sending to gmail.

This is essentially my code:

```
bodyhtml <- sendmailR::mime_part(paste0(
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>",
"<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>",
"<head>",
"<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>",
"<meta name='viewport' content='width=100%, initial-scale=1.0'/>",
"<style>",
"p { font-size: 95% }",
"table {border-collapse: collapse;}",
"th {background-color: #D3D3D3;}",
"tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #dfe7f2;}",
"</style>",
"</head>",
"<body>",
"<br>",
"<p>Hi ",recipient_name,",</p>",
"<br>",
"<div>",
"<p>Check out this awesome report as of <i>",report_date,"</i>.</p>",
"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, iudico quidam aliquid eos et, eam no vero democritum, ",
"no tempor laoreet indoctum sea. Cu malis persequeris has, duo an viris labitur pertinax, inani ignota molestiae sea eu. ",
"Pri et hinc quodsi. Ut ius dico animal sapientem. Cum ut vitae officiis definitionem. Sed ex atqui delectus, ",
"ea nulla diceret usu, liber eripuit te usu.</p>",
"</div>",
"<div>",
"<br>",
"<br>",
"</div>",
"<div>",
"<p>Consul invidunt expetendis has in, mea nemore habemus at, nibh eligendi tincidunt ex sit.:</p>",
"<ul>",
"<li><b>Primo</b></li>",
"<ul>",
"<li>Aeterno reprimique ea his. Pro ad brute dicat. Id eos habeo dicta tempor, ei perpetua scripserit theophrastus sed.</li>",
"</ul>",
"<li><b>Secundus</b></li>",
"<ul>",
"<li>Aeterno reprimique ea his. Pro ad brute dicat. Id eos habeo dicta tempor, ei perpetua scripserit theophrastus sed.</li>",
"</ul>",
"<li><b>Tertius</b></li>",
"<ul>",
"<li>Aeterno reprimique ea his. Pro ad brute dicat. Id eos habeo dicta tempor, ei perpetua scripserit theophrastus sed.</li>",
"</ul>",
"</ul>",
"</div>",
"<br>",
"<br>",
"<br>",
"<div>",
"<h2 style='color:#3b5998'>Primo</h2>",
"<p><i>(Up to 10 --see attachment for full list).</i></p>",
df_html1,
"<br>",
"<br>",
"<h2 style='color:#3b5998'>Secundus</h2>",
"<p><i>(Up to 10 --see attachment for full list).</i></p>",
df_html2,
"<br>",
"<br>",
"<h2 style='color:#3b5998'>Tertius</h2>",
"<p><i>(Up to 10 --see attachment for full list).</i></p>",
df_html3,
"</div>",
"<br>",
"<br>",
"<p style='color:#3b5998'>For further details, check out the ",
"<a href='https://www.mywebsite.com/dashboard'> dashboard</a>",
"<p style='color:#3b5998'>Questions? Comments? Reply directly to this email!</p>",
"<p style='color:#8b9dc3'>My Team Name</p>",
"<br>",
"<br>",
"</body>",
'</html>'
))

bodyhtml[["headers"]][["Content-Type"]] <- "text/html"

msg <- c(bodyhtml, sendmailR::mime_part("my_file_path.xlsx"))


sendmailR::sendmail(from = "me@email.com",
                    to = "you@email.com",
                    subject = "my subject line",
                    msg = msg)
```

Anybody have any ideas? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the first two lines (DOCTYPE and html tags) and that seems to have done the trick!

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>",
"<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' lang='en'>",
```

I found these links to be helpful:

- https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/which-code-should-i-include-in-every-email/
- https://emails.hteumeuleu.com/which-doctype-should-you-use-in-html-emails-cd323fdb793c